# Compute $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^4+1}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

### Problem:

Compute $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^4+1}dt$ possibly using Residue Theorem. I got this problem solving and understanding the following:

[Compute $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x + \cos x}{x^4+1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676680/compute-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-cos-xx41dx)

### My attempt:

I tried defining $f(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{z^4+1}$ and integrating in the first quadrant in an opportune slice, but I cannot reach any results. Is there a way to compute this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without complex analysis or residues, you can compute the antiderivative.

Use the roots of unity and then partial fraction decomposition to face four integrals looking like
$$I_a=\int \frac {e^{-t}}{t+a}$$ where $a$ is a complex number. This makes
$$I_a=e^a\, \text{Ei}(-(t+a))$$

For sure, the final result is not very pretty
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^4+1}dt=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}}\,\,G_{1,5}^{5,1}\left(\frac{1}{256}\right.\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{3}{4} \\
 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}
\end{array}
\right)$$ where appears the [Meijer G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

Numerically, this is $0.63047783491849835735$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maple evaluates this in terms of the exponential integral function
$$
\operatorname{Ei}_1(z) := \int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-zt}}{t}\;dt
$$
like this.  Define
$$
F(u) := \frac{u}{4}\;e^u\;\operatorname{Ei}_1(u) .
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t}}{t^4+1}\;dt = \sum F(u)
$$
where the sum is over all solutions $u$ of $u^4+1 = 0$.
That is:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t}}{t^4+1}\;dt = F\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
+F\left(\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
+F\left(\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
+F\left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) .
$$

In my opinion, this is more understandable than the Meijer G function.